# Show that, for the classical solutions of the wave equation, the following quantity is independent of $t$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

For any classical solution of the equation 
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} - \Delta u=0\quad (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1},
$$
show that the following quantity is independent of $t$: 
$$
M_1(t)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(\vec{x},t)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}(\vec{x},t)\,\mathrm{d}\vec{x}.
$$

Comment: @Harry49 I'm not sure how to tangibly go about proving the statement. I'm at a total loss.

Comment: I would start by computing the derivative $dM_1/dt$ and try to show that it equals zero. Please edit the question to include your thoughts

Comment: A bit strange formulation. Take $d=1$, $u(x,t)=\cos(x+t)$. The integral diverges.